# Excel VBA - When a value is selected another value is changed based on the selection made

Tags: excel, vba

OK so i have a combo box set up for:

`With Pclient
    Pclient.AddItem "CMN"
    Pclient.AddItem "RSS"
    Pclient.AddItem "ORD"
End With`

When i select a option for Pclient, i want Pcodclient to be setup to X so it sets the value the client code without having to imput it manually.

`Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Pclient.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = Pcodclient.Value`

How do i do this?
I tried running some 
`IF Pclient.Value = CMN then Pcodclient.Value = X`
before the Cells part... but it doesn't work.

EDIT:

Dim Pcodclient As String
  If Pclient.Value = "CMN" Then
    Pcodclient.Value = "LSR000"
  End If
  If Pclient.Value = "RSS" Then
    Pcodclient.Value = "LSR000"
  End If
  If Pclient.Value = "DEI" Then
    Pcodclient.Value = "LSR041"
  End If
  If Pclient.Value = "CTD" Then
    Pcodclient.Value = "LSR040"
  End If

```
'in randul 1
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Pclient.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = Pcodclient.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = Pptype.Value
```

I get a invalid qualifier on Pcodclient.Value = "LSR000"

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event to update the Pcodclient

```
Private Sub Pclient_Change()
  If Pclient.Value = "CMN" Then
    Pcodclient = "X"
  End If

  If Pclient.Value = "RSS" Then
    Pcodclient = "Y"
  End If

  If Pclient.Value = "ORD" Then
    Pcodclient = "Y"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub NewMethod()
'Do something
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't want to update on a change event, ok. I have shown you how to use the If and Pclient.Value

Comment: It gives me a error if i try to add this private sub in the middle of my private sub, sais it needs a end sub before it.

I'll try to change it to a `with` and define `Pcodclient` as a string

EDIT:

tried

`Dim Pcodclient As String
  If Pclient.Value = "CMN" Then
    Pcodclient.Value = "LSR000"
  End If
  If Pclient.Value = "RSS" Then
    Pcodclient.Value = "LSR000"
  End If
`

i get a error on `Pcodclient` :-/

Comment: I have added a procedure in the answer above. You cannot use a procedure/function within another procedure/function. So, place it outside.

Comment: Your edit shows Pcodclient is a String, hence I updated the code. Initially, my code treated Pcodclient as comboBox.

Comment: i am a bit confused about the private sub pclient_change()

i'll try to add this after my end sub (that comes after cells part)

Comment: i get a "object required" error ... 

i copied your code in a sub before and after my insert cells sub

Comment: Pcodclient is undefined. What is it ? If it is a control then which control ? If its a string variable, then remove Pcodclient.Value and just use Pcodclient.

Comment: It's a string. I need the text "LSR000" to be entered in column C when i choose CMN from the combobox Pclient. I removed .value, and it doesn't give any errors but it doesn't complete column C.

Comment: I hope Paddline_Click() is called after Pclient_Change(). Put a break point at "Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = Pcodclient" statement and check the value of Pcodclient.

Comment: yes it is called after it... both are private subs, don't know if that matters. the code in the pastebin is exactly how it is in my excel...

breakpoint says "pcodclient = empty"

Comment: Tried using a multi value per line combo box http://pastebin.com/FwuaqcDf but here i get a error on the array... :-/

Run-time error '9' subscript out of range

Comment: pcodclient should not be empty. Put a break point in Pclient_Change() and also at Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = Pcodclient" statements. Execution should break first in the Pclient_Change() then next time at 2nd break point

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a `Combobox` by linking it to the cell ([have a look here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/)). Now use `VLOOKUP` to get the values from a table. It would mean that you don't have to do any VBA